# Why a Graves-LSTM Cell has 4 + 7 = 11 weigths in deeplearning4j?

Tags: neural-network, lstm, deeplearning4j

**Why a Graves-LSTM layer Cell has 11 weigths, and what is their purpose**?

Given below example can generate weigth list:

```
MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
        .list()
        .layer(0, new GravesLSTM.Builder()
                .nIn(1)
                .nOut(1)
                .activation("sigmoid")
                .weightInit(WeightInit.ZERO)
                .build()
                )
        .build());
model.init();

System.out.println("Weigths: " + model.paramTable());
```

**out:**

> Weigths:
>
> {0_W=[0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00], 0_RW=[0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00,
>   0.00, 0.00, 0.00], 0_b=[0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00]}
>
> **( 11 weigth + 4 bias )**

in contrast here is the output **using DenseLayer** instead of GravesLSTM:

> Weigths: {0_W=0.00, 0_b=0.00}
>
> **( 1 weight + 1 bias, this is clear. )**

Comment: Please join the DL4J community on Gitter. A lot of people there can answer your question: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Comment: We answered this in the community already. The extra weights are related to the extra gates an LSTM has (eg: the forget gate)